# How to change the document type of a CCB file in SpriteBuilder?

Tags: spritebuilder

I have created a CCB file as a *Scene* now I would like to change it into a *Layer* because I want the size of the CCB file to be larger than one screen.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Officially SpriteBuilder doesn't allow you to change the document type of a file, however, there is a way around this. The information about the size type is stored in the CCB file.

1. Close SpriteBuilder (to avoid that the cache overrides your changes to the CCB file)
2. Open the CCB file of the Scene that you want to change into a Layer with a text editor of your choice. Search for the `docDimensionsType`. As of SpriteBuilder 1.1 the value of this entry corresponds to this enum:

   ```
   enum {
       kCCBDocDimensionsTypeFullScreen,
       kCCBDocDimensionsTypeNode,
       kCCBDocDimensionsTypeLayer,
   };
   ```

   So if you want to have a layer, change that value to **2**.
3. Reopen the project in SpriteBuilder and you will now see that you
   can change the size of the stage, you now have a *Layer* instead of
   *Scene*.